# CAKEPHP3 REST API point to a different controller?

Tags: rest, controller, routes, cakephp-3.0

I believe I am missing something here. I am trying to point a route to a custom controller:

```
Router::scope('/myAPI/', function ($routes) {
    $routes->extensions(['json', 'xml']);

    $routes->resources('some_value',
            [
            'controller'=>'SomeValue',
            'only' => ['index', 'create', 'update', 'delete'],
            'id'=>'[0-9]+'
            ]); 
});
```

Therefore the URL I am wanting is **~mydomain~/myAPI/some_value**.

I would want this to point to the SomeValueController instead of looking for some_valueController. However the controller definition is ignored in this case and instead cakephp3 looks for some_valueController instead which I would rather avoid to try and keep with cakephp's naming conventions (and make use of the cake bake console to create a lot of controllers for models for me) but I would like to specify this custom URL.

What have I missed here?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, if you TitleCase the name it works:

```
    $routes->resources( 'SomeValue',
            [
            'only' => ['index', 'create', 'update', 'delete'],
            'id'=>'[0-9]+'
            ]);
```

This allows the URL of some_value and points to the correct controller.

Posted just in case it helps someone else.